# Execution killed with signal 11 (could be triggered by violating memory limits)

Tags: c++, memory, limit

This code should take two string as imput. These strings have only alphabetical characthers(a-z & A-Z) but it gives me "Execution killed with signal 11 (could be triggered by violating memory limits)". But i don't understand why since I use two arrays car and carQ to store information about the presence of alphabetical charachters by doing car[char-'A'] and this index is always great or equal than zero and less than 60. Do you have any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <bitset>

#define MAX_N 20000005

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> ii ;
typedef vector< ii >   vii ;
typedef vector<int> vi ;

int n,m,s,car[60],carQ[60];
string W,S;
queue<char> q;

int main() {
    ifstream in; ofstream out;
    in.open("input.txt"); out.open("output.txt");

    in>>n>>m;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        in>>S[i];
        car[(int)(S[i]-'A')]++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        in>>W[i];

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        if(!car[(int)(W[i]-'A')])
            while(!q.empty()){
                carQ[q.front()-'A']--;
                q.pop();
            }
        else{
            q.push(W[i]);
            carQ[(int)(W[i]-'A')]++;
            while(carQ[(int)(W[i]-'A')]>car[(int)(W[i]-'A')]){
                carQ[q.front()-'A']--;
                q.pop();
            }
            if(q.size()==n)
                s++;
        }
    }

    out<<s;       

    in.close(); out.close(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: run with the debugger... Can you post an example of input.txt? or the expected format?

Comment: Add lots of logging to the program to see how far it gets and what it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    in>>S[i];
```

This doesn't make sense. Since `S` is empty, `S[i]` can't possibly exist.

Comment: You're right...I forgot that i was using a string and not an array of char. But when I submitted this version I got 30/100 points...in fact for some cases it works, how is it possible?

Comment: @user3653507 Code with bugs in it won't do what you expect. Fix the bugs and the mystery will go away.